# compress files in bash using screen and setting compression level

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gnu-screen

I want to compress a large folder using tar, xz and also using screen to get the verbose output.

Without screen, the command is:

```
$ XZ_OPT=-9 tar cJfv mydirectory.tar.xz mydirectory
```

Now with screen, all I get is immediately a [screen is terminating], I assume because of the XZ_OPT environment variable

```
$ screen -L XZ_OPT=-9 tar cJfv mydirectory.tar.xz mydirectory
```

I tried the following below, which makes a tar.xz file which that is increasing in size as time progresses, but screen does not show me any output, despite the v flag for tar, which I would like to have

```
$ screen -L $(XZ_OPT=-9 tar cJfv mydirectory.tar.xz mydirectory)
```

How do I also get the output of tar shown?

Comment: That `$()` attempt is running `tar` in a sub-shell and then putting its output on the command line of the `screen` command. Try setting `XZ_OPT` on the `screen` command itself `XZ_OPT=-9 screen ....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in fact, the problem with the original command is the shell assignment (and it quite likely is as that's a shell feature and `screen` isn't expecting that at that point then a possible solution would be to set the variable in the environment of `screen` itself and let it "bleed into" the environment of the `tar` command.

```
XZ_OPT=-9 screen -L tar cJfv mydirectory.tar.xz mydirectory
```

If that doesn't work for some reason (or can't be used because it needs to be limited to only that specific command (and not other screen-spawned shells that might be opened) then a shell script that gets run is possibly the only answer.